# selective library linking Xcode 6 / LLVM 6

Tags: ios, xcode6, static-linking

I selectively link a library depending on the configuration in my project build settings. i.e.

Debug: -l libcws_ps
Release: -l libcws

In library search paths, I point to the directory that contains these 2 .a libraries.

I'll point out that this worked on Xcode 5, but now on Xcode 6 it's not linking properly and I'm getting undefined symbol errors. If I link using the usual method - 'link binary with libraries', then it works - but then I don't have the configuration based linking.

Any ideas how to fix this, or at least some clues how I get debug it?

```
Libtool /Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilmFlexMovies-ddwyjuvbhaqgqralpjczhprnltla/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libiOSIrdetoLibrary.a normal armv7
cd /Users/dave/Developer/GIT/FilmFlex/iOS/Submodules/iOSModelController/Submodules/iOSIrdetoLibrary
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilmFlexMovies-ddwyjuvbhaqgqralpjczhprnltla/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -LCloakwareStreaming/lib/ios -L/Users/dave/Developer/GIT/FilmFlex/iOS/Submodules/iOSModelController/Submodules/iOSIrdetoLibrary/CloakwareStreaming/lib/ios -filelist /Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilmFlexMovies-ddwyjuvbhaqgqralpjczhprnltla/Build/Intermediates/iOSIrdetoLibrary.build/Release-iphoneos/iOSIrdetoLibrary.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iOSIrdetoLibrary.LinkFileList -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/dave/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilmFlexMovies-ddwyjuvbhaqgqralpjczhprnltla/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libiOSIrdetoLibrary.a
```

Comment: Hmmm, that should work.  Can you please add the command line that Xcode 6 is using during the link to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RTFM... or RTFRN... [Xcode 6 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc6_release_notes/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW2)

"Xcode will no longer pass options in the build setting OTHER_LDFLAGS to libtool when building static libraries, nor will it pass options in OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS to the Mach-O linker when building any other kind of product. Previously all options in both settings would be passed to both tools. Make sure that options are in the correct build setting for the product type, static library, or other component being built. (4285249)"

So it just wasn't even passing my 'other linker flags'. I needed to move them to 'other librarian flags'.